# Angular 2 filtering complex data using pipes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a complex data structure like that (some tabs with tables of IPs as content):

```
tabs : [
    { 
      data: [
        { ip: '', vms: [ { hostname: 'some'}, { hostname: 'some2'} ] },         
        { ip: '', vms: [....] }
      ],
      name: 'tab1',
    },
    {...}

]
```

Now I want to filter over hostname field.

I wrote a code:

```
export class VMsTabFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], filterValue: string): any {
    console.log(filterValue)
    if(filterValue == undefined || filterValue == '') {
        console.log(items)
        return items;
    }

    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter(item => {
        let found = false;



          item.data = item.data.filter(record => {
                for(let vm of record.vms) {
                    if(String(vm.hostname).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) !== -1) {
                        found = true; 
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });

            if(found) {
                return item;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

template

```
<ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of data | vmsTabFilter:filterValue; let i = index" [class.active]="tab.active" title="{{tab.name}}">
        <template ngbTabContent>
            <my-table [data]="prepareData(tab.data)" [defaultSort]="1"></my-table>
        </template>
    </ngb-tab>
```

It seems to filter tabs properly but rows in table with IPs are not filtered well. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are the "rows in table with IPs" coming from "prepareData(tab.data)"? I think you may need to share more of your code if that is the case?

Comment: there is no more code. I have tabs where content is a table. When I put "hostname" into <input [(ngModel)]="filterValue"> I want to have filtered tabs and rows in table also. "prepareData" just changes dictionary which I passed in first post to format understandable for <my-table> component

Comment: The Pipe only filters the tabs. You will get all "tab.data" objetcs that belong to each matching tab unless somethign happens in prepareData() that I can't see.  If you get "tab.data" that belongs to some other tab, I would suspect there is a problem inside "prepareData(), which is why I asked about it first. There could also be something wrong with your data structure. Double check your data to make sure it is good.